# Apache2 - Set Document Root based on subdirectory

Tags: php, apache2, virtualhost

I have a default Virtual Host. It is configured to watch Document Root inside `/var/www/html` and works great. But I have a problem. I have multiple sites inside subdirectories and I don't know how to set Document Root for each of them. For example, `/var/www/html/test`, `/var/www/html/test2`, etc. When I include file from `/var/www/html/test`, it searches inside `var/www/html`. For example, I include file like `include_once '/core.php'`, but I have an error `Failed opening required '/var/www/html/core.php'`, because there is no current file here. Is it possible to set Document Root for each of directories inside main Virtual Host? Thank you!

My main Virtual Host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    AccessFileName .htaccess

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Also, you can say, that I need to use relative paths, but it isn't possible in some ways, because, sometimes, I work with ready sites, created by another people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to set Document Root for each of directories inside
> main Virtual Host?

Short answer is no, you cannot. 1 Document Root per Virtual Host. In order to understand how the things are working you need to understand what is the [directives context](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context). Lets take as an example [VirtualHost directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost). As we can see from the docs it has only 1 Context which is Server Config. And server config context tells next:

> directive may be used in the server
> configuration files (e.g., httpd.conf), but not within any
> VirtualHost or Directory containers. It is not allowed in
> .htaccess files at all.

But [DoocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#DocumentRoot) has two contexts: server config and virtual host. Rest you should figure out for yourself ;)

There are plenty ways how you can achieve desired result

1. [Running several name-based web sites on a single IP address](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#purename)
2. [Running different sites on different ports](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#port)
3. [Mixed port-based and ip-based virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#ipport)

Hope that this answer will help you!

Comment: I have one more question. Is it possible to run several web-sites without domain on a single IP address? For example, create two different virtual hosts and set for each different directories? After that, run sites by example: `IP/test1`, `IP/test2`, `IP/test3`, etc. And for each of these sites directory root should be like `/var/www/test1`, `/var/www/test2`, etc.

Comment: Yes, but you will need to use ports for this.
Example: `<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:81>...</VirtualHost>`, `<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:82>...</VirtualHost>` and in **httpd.conf** you need to add **Listen** directives for each port(81 and 82 are test1 and test2 accordingly).
Example(in httpd.conf file): `Listen 81 Listen 82` .
@Shellai

Comment: Okey, thanks! I have also read about Server Alias and Server Name. Is it possible to use them for different Virtual Hosts on the same IP without domains? Or is it only possible by using ports?

Comment: [Here is the good self explaining answer including DNS explanation](https://serverfault.com/questions/520195/how-does-servername-and-serveralias-work#answer-520201) @Shellai